# Jquery div selection? On hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with selecting external div to change the css element.

I had:

```
<script>
$(".shares").hover(function(){
    $('.homenetworks').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.totalshares').addClass('hidden');
    $('.catlink').addClass('hidden');
    $('.shareimage').addClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $('.homenetworks').addClass('hidden');
    $('.totalshares').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.catlink').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.shareimage').removeClass('hidden');
});

</script>
```

Which worked to the desired effect, however it applied it to every instance of this on the page. I then found out about `$(this).find` to only effect the selected one.

```
<script>
$(".shares").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.homenetworks').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.totalshares').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.catlink').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.shareimage').addClass('hidden');
},function(){
    $(this).find('.homenetworks').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.totalshares').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.catlink').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('.shareimage').removeClass('hidden');
});

</script>
```

However this removes the class from .homenetworks and adds the class hidden to .totalshares but it no longer effects .totalshares and .catlink.

The structure of the divs is like so:

```
<div class="newsbutton">
   <div class="catlink">
      Link
   </div>
   <div class="shareimage">
      Img
   </div>
   <div class="shares">
      <div class="totalshares">
         Shares
      </div>
      <div class="homenetworks hidden">
         Content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like when a user hovers over .totalshares it hides totalshares,shareimage,newsbutton and then shows homenetworks. (By using display:none under the css class .hidden).

Anyone got any ideas what is possibly going wrong, can (this).find not search up levels on div structure?

Thanks

Comment: `(this).find` only searches in childs of `this` element. To avoid that use siblings() like Arun P Johny mentioned, or use the ``.parent()`` function before you use `.find()` (this only works in your case, not in all, depending on the strukture and the parent elements.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `catlink` and `shareimage` are siblings of `shares` not descendants so `.find()` will not be able to find them

```js
$(".shares").hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.homenetworks').removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).find('.totalshares').addClass('hidden');
  $(this).siblings('.catlink, .shareimage').addClass('hidden');
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.homenetworks').addClass('hidden');
  $(this).find('.totalshares').removeClass('hidden');
  $(this).siblings('.catlink, shareimage').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.newsbutton {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
.catlink,
.shareimage {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  height: 30px;
}

.shares {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsbutton">
  <div class="catlink">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="shareimage">
    Img
  </div>
  <div class="shares">
    <div class="totalshares">
      Shares
    </div>
    <div class="homenetworks hidden">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newsbutton">
  <div class="catlink">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="shareimage">
    Img
  </div>
  <div class="shares">
    <div class="totalshares">
      Shares
    </div>
    <div class="homenetworks hidden">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="newsbutton">
  <div class="catlink">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="shareimage">
    Img
  </div>
  <div class="shares">
    <div class="totalshares">
      Shares
    </div>
    <div class="homenetworks hidden">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to initially select `.newsbutton` rather than `.shares`?

Comment: Fantastic, I was not aware of .siblings! thank you. .newsbutton will have a url in that needs to be clickable still.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use CSS in this instance, instead you could simply use the hide() method within JQuery and reference each class in your selector.

```
$(".shares").hover(function(){
    $('.homenetworks').show();
    $('.totalshares, .catlink, .shareimag').hide();
},function(){
    $('.homenetworks').hide();
    $('.totalshares, .catlink, .shareimag').show();
});
```

Unless you require css logic specifically this will work for you

Comment: I prefer the solution by adding a "hidden"-class. `.hide() and .show()` may be faster and more comfortable, but the code is better to read if there are html classes which tell you about their visibility.

Comment: @DerVampyr Yes but it adds to the complexity of the script and goes against the idea of actually using the JQuery framework when the classes are provided for you to use. "Write less, do more"

Answer (score 0):

Add your first code and then specify height and width for .shares,It will hide all other divs and show
homenetworks

```
<style>
.shares{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>
```